# How to retrieve the custom push id from fire base database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble fetching the custom push id which is created while pushing the value. [image]

I want to fetch "4wJIGRCkYrZqFpb401hSmgHeBOI3" from rated_user node. Any help will be really useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say database reference for rated_users is this `RatedUser`

```
  valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String key = postSnapshot.getKey();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };



  RatedUser.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: this did not work.. it gives me "rated_users" even though my ref is 
"https://**************/rated_users"

Comment: Updated it , the key will contain all the push ids .

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to archive your goal.

```
    private DatabaseReference ref;
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://xxxx.firebase.com/rated_users");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        try {
                            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
String value = dataSnapshot.child("key").getValue(String.class);
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            String valws = e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

PS:
I did a quick sample it works for me.
[image]

Comment: this gives me "rated_users" in the key and value gives null.

Comment: Please make sure you've set proper "rules" in the database if you're not using authentication.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

All i did was added a foreach loop:

```
 for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.e("children" , snapshot.getKey()+"");
            }
```

this gave me the key "4wJIGRCkYrZqFpb401hSmgHeBOI3"